# Unable to get Remove() Protect() working with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to give users of a Google Sheet the ability to protect a row in a sheet. By setting a value in a cell to "√" (from a dropdown list) I want to protect the row. If the same or any other user wants to change a value in the row, I want them to be able to remove "√" with "-" (also from the dropdown list).

I'm using the onEdit() event.

I'm able to protect the desired range, but having problems removing the protection, remove() just isn't working.

I can get remove to work in the following command, but what happens is protect() simply creates a new protected range and remove() removes it. I'm trying to remove a range created by someone else, some time in the past.

var result = range.protect().remove()

I'm about 8 hours into this (mostly searching for an answer).

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a protected range, you have to get it by listing the protections:

`// Remove all range protections in the spreadsheet that the user has permission to edit.
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var protections = 
    ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
      var protection = protections[i];
      if (protection.canEdit()) {
        protection.remove();
      }
    }`

See the samples/docs @ https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection.  Calling `range.protect()` will always create a new protection.

Comment: Thank you @Sam Berlin...I've seen this snippet in my travels...the problem is how do I find the row to which I want to remove the protection? I.e., how do I find the row in the range equal to the row in the sheet the user is on in order to apply the remove()?